# PDO и класс Medoo

Tags: pdo, php, mysql

Как то странно, я сам не понял как я перешел на PDO используя класс http://medoo.in/ и только сейчас уже жалею об этом, но переписывать весь сайт это же бред, начал возиться с ним. Собственно проблема есть в функции get, но я могу обойтись и без нее. А самое страшное что случилось это функция update. Иной раз самый простой запрос выполняется от 3х до 5ти сек. А когда на сайте два запроса с update то сайт просто висит. Самое главное это то что сама функция срабатывает быстро, а зависает все вот в этом месте:

```
 foreach ($commands as $value) {
   $this->pdo->exec($value);    
 }
```

Подскажите, может кто знает почему так может быть. Писал разработчику ответа так и не получил :(

Comment: Библиотека какая-то очень странная (ни одного внятного phpdoc, семь!!! уровней вложенности в некоторых местах, ручная подстановка кавычек), но я не увидел там ничего, что могло бы тормозить. Попробуйте выполнить апдейт на чистом PDO, посмотрите, сколько будет выполняться. Ну и посмотреть, что валяется в $commands, тоже не мешало бы.  
upd. вы update c where же делаете, правильно?

Comment: update без where и прочего. microtime показал что все виснет на $this->pdo->exec($value); Сейчас попробую на чистом PDO отпишу

Comment: @wwwplaton, вы понимаете, что без where у вас вся таблица обновляется? Все это время exec будет "стоять". Впроыем, приведенный выше кусок кода относится к инциализации класса, еще до апдейта.

Comment: Так то я всегда использовал такой запрос и проблем не было. $db->update(DB_USERS, ["user_online" => 0], ["user_online_time[<]" => time() - 60]); что тут может виснуть? когда юзеров всего 100

Comment: @wwwplaton, третий аргумент - это как раз таки where.

Comment: пробовал без него только один запрос 5.2642340660095 сек.

Comment: на чистом PDO то же самое, я в панике, куда копать?

Comment: @wwwplaton, если хостинг shared - писать в техподдержку, вполне возможно, у них перегружены сервера БД/очень плохая сеть, и по этому поводу надо им написать пару претензий. Если свой собственный - позапускать те же команды из консоли, выполнить explain (на shared наверняка тоже можно). Проверить, что будет при процедурном подходе, тоже не мешает, однако я все-таки склоняюсь к проблемам на стороне БД.

Ну и еще раз отмечу, что вышеприведенное место устанавливает коннект, и если сами запросы бегают нормально, то жто довольно странно.